# Bounded Type Parameters @see and @link javadoc

Tags: java, generics, javadoc

How do you reference a method in javadoc's @see and @link if they have Bonded type parameters?

Example:

```
public class A { }
public interface I<J> { }

public class F {
    public static <T extends A & I<B>, B> String newThing(T bondedTypeObject, List<B> list) {
      /*...*/
    }

    public static <T extends A & I<B>, B> String newThing(T bondedTypeObject, B anotherObject) {
      /*...*/
    }


    /**
     * Uses {@link #newThing(T bondedTypeObject, List<B> list) newThing} to create a super new thing.
     */
    public static String createSuperNewThing(...) {
       return newThing(...);
    }
}
```

How do you write the javadoc for createSuperNewThing link to the correct newThing method?

The Oracle documentation isn't very clear in cases like this:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#specifyingname

Comment: Eclipse autocompletes them. Have you tried it? Just #methodName `[ctrl+space]`

Comment: @BalusC Does it do it correctly? Tried autocompleting it in NetBeans and it generated `{@link #newThing(, java.util.List) }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify the [erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) of the arguments, for example:

```
/**
 * Uses {@link newThing(A bondedTypeObject, List list)} to create...
 */
```

Note that the erasure of a type parameter `T extends SomeClass & SomeInterface` is `SomeClass`.

Comment: Thanks Paul! Using jdk 7 javadoc it looks like instead of A, it uses the same letter as the original method signature. So for this case it is:
`{@link newThing(T bondedTypeObject, List list)}` but javadoc is smart enough to pick up either one.

Comment: Interesting! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example from the Oracle Java docs. To link to this method in Collections

```
static <K,V> Map<K,V> synchronizedMap(Map<K,V> m)
```

you would use the link:

```
{@link Collections.html#synchronizedMap(Map)}
```